# Unable To set Geo location using remoteWebdriver(like saucelab, privateGrid)

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to set geoLocation in remoteWebdriver But i'm getting below exception.its working in ChromeDriver();

Code i used:

```
WebDriver driver =  new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps); 
((LocationContext) driver).setLocation(new Location(12.91072, 77.60998, 100));
```

Error I am getting

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.html5.LocationContext`

Answer (score 1):

Nagu!
I also have this issue before and I resolved it using augmenter.
In your case it would be something like:

```
((LocationContext) new Augmenter().augment(getDriver())).setLocation(new Location(12.91072, 77.60998, 100));
```

You can find more in fo in https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/Augmenter.html

Comment: I'm getting the same `ClassCastException` even using the `Augmenter`, how's that possible? Is there something else to configure?